# Merge columns from the a DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, merge, apache-spark-sql

I've DataFrame with 4 columns and want to merge the first 2 columns with the last 2 columns in a new DataFrame.

The data is identical, the order is irrelevant and any duplicates must remain.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
        
df = spark.createDataFrame([
["This is line 1","xxxx12","This is line 5","hhhh29"],
["This is line 2","yyyy23","This is line 6","kkkk47"],
["This is line 3","zzzz64","This is line 7","llll88"],
["This is line 4","gggg37","This is line 8","ssss84"],
]).toDF("col_a", "col_b", "col_c", "col_d")
```

New DataFrame:

```
+---------------+-------+
| col_1         |col_2  |
+-------------- +-------+
|This is line 1 |xxxx12 |
|This is line 5 |hhhh29 |
|This is line 2 |yyyy23 |
|This is line 6 |kkkk47 |
|This is line 3 |zzzz64 |
|This is line 7 |llll88 |
|This is line 4 |gggg37 |
|This is line 8 |ssss84 |
+---------------+-------+
```

How do I get this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If order is not important, you can use `unionAll`:

```
df2 = df.selectExpr(
    "col_a as col_1", "col_b as col_2"
).unionAll(
    df.selectExpr("col_c as col_1", "col_d as col_2")
)

df2.show()
+--------------+------+
|         col_1| col_2|
+--------------+------+
|This is line 1|xxxx12|
|This is line 2|yyyy23|
|This is line 3|zzzz64|
|This is line 4|gggg37|
|This is line 5|hhhh29|
|This is line 6|kkkk47|
|This is line 7|llll88|
|This is line 8|ssss84|
+--------------+------+
```

Or you can use `stack`, which keeps order:

```
df2 = df.selectExpr("stack(2, col_a, col_b, col_c, col_d) as (col_1, col_2)")

df2.show()
+--------------+------+
|         col_1| col_2|
+--------------+------+
|This is line 1|xxxx12|
|This is line 5|hhhh29|
|This is line 2|yyyy23|
|This is line 6|kkkk47|
|This is line 3|zzzz64|
|This is line 7|llll88|
|This is line 4|gggg37|
|This is line 8|ssss84|
+--------------+------+
```